# List all files with multiple hardlinks and related path

Tags: command-line, hard-link

How can I list all files with hardlinks and the associated paths?

It should be a sorted list, by the inode ID.

EDIT:
sure, I mean all files with a hardlink number >=2

I thought about a list like

```
INODE_ID   FILEPATH

1234 /tmp/test1
1234 /tmp/test2
3245 /tmp/test4
3245 /tmp/test3
```

Comment: all files have hard links ;)

Comment: This looks like a better answer for creating a complete list of all multi-linked inodes: https://superuser.com/a/904373/175529

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, in that case maybe

```
for i in /tmp/**; do 
  [[ -f "$i" ]] && 
  (( $(stat -c %h "$i") > 1 )) && 
  stat -c '%i %n' "$i"
done | sort -V
```

#### Notes

- `for i in *` for each file in the current directory
- `[[ -f "$i" ]] &&` if it is a regular file and
- `(( $(stat -c %h "$i") > 1 ))` if it has more than one hard link
- `stat -c '%i %n'` print its inode number and name
- `| sort -V` and sort that output "naturally"

You can replace `*` with the path to the files, for example `/tmp/*` which will cause the full path to be printed. If you want to search recursively, you can use `shopt -s globstar` and then `**` in the path, for example `/tmp/**`

`find` has a `-links` test but <del>it seems to only take an integer</del> you'll have to read [Ravexina's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/910707/527764) for a solution that uses it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know shopt, but your version also list folders. I made a small modification: ```shopt -s globstar;for i in /tmp/**; do [[ -f "$i" ]] && (( $(stat -c %h "$i") > 1 )) && stat -c '%i %n' "$i"; done | sort -V```

Comment: ah ok - edited it :) for `shopt` see [this page of the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html)

Answer (score 8):

Here is my solution with `find`:

```
find . -links +1 -type f -name '*' -printf '%i %p\n' | sort
```

- `.` : search in current directory, you can change it to anything else, e.g: `/`, `~/ravexina`, etc.
- `-links +1` : only files with more than of 1 link ( >= 2 ).
- `-type f` : only files (not directories, sym links, pipe files, etc).
- `-name '*'`: all files with anything in their names no matter what.
- `-printf '%i %p\n'`: only print `inode`, `file path` and a new line`\n`.
- `sort` : sort lines based on inodes.

Comment: oh nice, I couldn't figure out how to get the `-links`  test to take "more than 1" (obviously I did not try hard enough). I don't think you need to specify `-k1` to `sort` since it will sort on the first column anyway

Comment: Yeah, I figure it out from `-size` usage ;)